# Django Generic Relation Serialization

Tags: python, django, generics, django-rest-framework

Lets say I have an abstract base class, and a few child classes

```
class Food(models.Model):
    weight = models.SmallIntegerField(
        null=True
    )
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
class Burger(Food):
    ...
class Pizza(Food):
    toppings_amt = models.PositiveIntegerField(
         null=True
    )
    ....
class Plate(models.Model):
    food = GenericRelation('??????')
```

How would I go about adding the generic foreign key to the child classes of the abstract base class? If I add it to the Food class like this:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    class Meta:
         abstract=True
class Plate(models.Model):
    food = GenericRelation('Food')
```

Then it gives me an error:

```
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

Which I believe is due to me using an abstract class as the generic relationship which doesn't have an actual table in the db, so it's just pointing  back to a string.

I'd like to be able to serialize the 'Plate' model, so Id Have

```
class GenericFoodField(serializers.RelatedField):
    to_representation(self, value):
         if isinstance(value, Pizza):
            return PizzaSerializer(value).data
         elif isinstance(value, Burger):
            return BurgerSerializer(value).data
         raise Exception('Unexpected food type')
class PlateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     food = GenericFoodField(
        read_only=True,
        required=False,
        allow_null=True,
        many=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model=Plate
        fields = ('food', ...)
```

with the point being that PizzaSerializer would have different fields than BurgerSerializer. However, if the Food class is not abstract then the serializer won't interpret what subclass the Food object it is.

Any ideas for how to form the generic relations? I had previously had a model that took in two GenericForeignKeys and so i could do

```
class GenericFoodField(serializers.RelatedField):
    to_representation(self, value):
         if isinstance(value.food_object, Pizza):
            return PizzaSerializer(value.food_object).data
```

But that seemed really messy and like not the right way to be going about things.

Comment: For now I ended up just using django polymorphic. It works for what I'm trying to do but I'm almost positive it's overkill for what I am trying to do